# Drop-down box and buttons like in gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: gmail]

How to do this effects for `<option>` and `<button>` with CSS and JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not real `<select>` or `<button>` element. The real form element would be (if it was a form element at the beginning) replaced with simple styled `<ul>` (one of the options). And javascript is used to hide select element, replace it with list and attach events to list items / anchors.

Edit: Gmail apparentyl doesn't use list, but divs. That's also an option.. logic behind it is still same.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://aext.net/2009/12/incredible-drop-down-menu-solution-with-css-only/). You have to change images and colors.